# У меня ошибка с пакетамч pip

Tags: windows, pycharm, pip

У меня эта ошибка всегда когда я хочу что-то сделать с пакетам pip.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В проектах PyCharm обычно создаётся виртуальное окружение, может вам нужно его включить?

Comment: Спасибо большое!